Why is my infinite scroll component not taking up the entire width of the screen?
I'm not sure if this is a problem with my usage of infinite scroll or inadequate understanding of flexbox.
Here's some simplified code. Infinite Scroll is put in flexbox. The contents are a div using tailwind. I want the contents of infinite scroll to stretch the entire page, but I am instead seeing this:

import React, { useState } from "react";
import InfiniteScroll from 'react-infinite-scroll-component';

const Home = () => {    
    const [items, setItems] = useState([0,1,2,3]);
    function fetchData() {
        return null
    }

    return (
        <div style= {{display:'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap', flexDirection: "row"}}>
        <InfiniteScroll
        style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
        dataLength={items.length} //This is important field to render the next data
        next={fetchData}
        hasMore={true}
        loader={<h4>Loading...</h4>}
        endMessage={
            <p style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
            <b>Yay! You have seen it all</b>
            </p>
        }
        // below props only if you need pull down functionality
        refreshFunction={fetchData}
        pullDownToRefresh
        pullDownToRefreshThreshold={50}
        pullDownToRefreshContent={
            <h3 style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>&#8595; Pull down to refresh</h3>
        }
        releaseToRefreshContent={
            <h3 style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>&#8593; Release to refresh</h3>
        }>
            <div className="w-full h-full mt-1 sm:mt-6 flex flex-col space-y-4">
                oi
            </div>
        </InfiniteScroll>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Home;


your flexbox is horizontal, but you need vertical. the parent div does not need to specify any properties at all. see example from component author

@AlexeyObukhov Can you clarify why I need vertical? I have other components next to the infinite scroll I'm laying out.

Your infinite scroll isn't 100% width, only its child

@ZachJensz Yeah, and even if i get the parent to be full width, the infinite scroll component is not full width. So how do I fix this?

Remove CSS from parent of infinite scroll element. I'm not familiar with this infinite scroll component but if it's a standard block element it should just take the full width of its parent in flow layout without any CSS applied

@ZachJensz If i removed the parent's css, how will it be inheriting any layout from its parent?

Make a reproducible example snippet and include the any other relevant siblings of infinite scroll that require having flexbox there
